# Thread wait communication

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python script which calls plugins on a separate thread. The plugins must execute some commands and wait for a signal from the main script before they can proceed.

I used wait() in the plugin and set and clear in the calling script but I guess that once the plugin thread is called the main script waits for the thread to complete before continuing. Thus the set and wait are never called and the program hangs.  I have attached a simplified version of code.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

import threading, os, sys, re, imp

e = threading.Event()

class PluginLoader():

#    atexit.register(detective.terminate())
    ## getPlugins - Locate all plugins with plugin directory
    #  @param self          Class object pointer
    #  @param moduleName    Name of module

    def getPlugins(self, moduleName):        
        try: 
            # Folder in which the plugins are stored
            self.pluginFolder = "/tmp/plugins"

            # Give the value of the main module in json file. (This is the name omitting the .py extension)
            self.mainModule = moduleName[0].strip(" ")

            # Load plugin array 
            plugins = []
            possibleplugins = os.listdir(self.pluginFolder)        

            # Iterate over plugins to determine applicable plugin
            for i in possibleplugins:              
                location=os.path.join(self.pluginFolder, i)

                # Skip if not directory or plugin not in directory
                if not os.path.isdir(location) or not self.mainModule + ".py" in os.listdir(location): 
                    continue

                # Otherwise, find the module
                info = imp.find_module(self.mainModule, [location])        
                plugins.append({"name": i, "info": info})    

            return plugins            
        except OSError:
            print "File or folder  not found"            


    ## loadPlugin - Load plugin into script
    #  @param self      Class object pointer
    #  @param plugin    Plugin object pointer
    #  @return Plugin object

    def loadPlugin(self, plugin):
        return imp.load_module(self.mainModule, *plugin["info"])


class Threads:

    def run(self):
        self.tuck()
        raw_input("press entr")            
        e.set()

    def tuck(self):
        moduleName= ["hello"]
        for i in pluginLoader.getPlugins(moduleName):
            plugin = pluginLoader.loadPlugin(i)            
            threading.Thread(name = "block", target=plugin.run(e)).start() 
            e.set()
            e.clear()       

pluginLoader=PluginLoader()    
t= Threads()
t.run()
```

the following script must be copied into a /tmp/plugins directory and named hello.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from thre import *

class wait:
    flag = ""
    def run(self,e):
        self.flag = e
        print "in main thread"
        self.prints(e)
        e.wait()
        threading.Thread(target=self.prints12).start() 

    def prints(self,e):
        for i in xrange(10):
            print "world"

    def prints12(self):
        for i in xrange(10):
            print "Hey"


w = wait()

def run (e)            :
    w.run(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be here:

```
threading.Thread(name = "block", target=plugin.run(e)).start()
```

`plugin.run(e)` will directly call the run method of the plugin and block, therefore deadlocking your program. This probably should be:

```
threading.Thread(name = "block", target=plugin.run, args=(e,)).start()
```